# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xae in position 1: invalid start byte

Tags: python, pandas, unicode

I'm trying to read a csv with the pd.read_csv, but the error above keeps on popping up.

I've tried to do different encodings and other stuff but it still didn't work. Here's the dataset I'm trying to download from:https://github.com/several27/FakeNewsCorpus/releases/tag/v1.0

Here's the code:

```
dataset = pd.read_csv('/content/news.csv.z02', encoding='UTF-8'
)




Errors:


UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-93ad6e1344ea> in <module>()
----> 1 dataset = pd.read_csv('/content/news.csv.z02', encoding='UTF-8')

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in init(self, src, kwds)
   2008         kwds["usecols"] = self.usecols
   2009 
-> 2010         self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, kwds)
   2011         self.unnamed_cols = self._reader.unnamed_cols
   2012 

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.cinit()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._get_header()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._tokenize_rows()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error()

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xae in position 1: invalid start byte
```

Comment: It looks like the file is on your hard drive. How did you download it? These are compressed files, have you unzipped them? The web site suggests _use a tool like "The Unarchiver" on mac to open them up._

Comment: If the archive is broken up over multiple files, you'll need to put the archive back together and unzip it first

Comment: @tdelaney I was unable to unzip the file, also I'm on windows 10, not mac.

Comment: @ifly6 How do you put it back together, and do you unzip it before you put it back together?

Comment: The first 4 bytes of the first CSV is `b'PK\x07\x08` which is the magic number for a spanned zip file. I don't think that a simple concatenation of the files will work... but not sure and I'm not going to download the whole project to see. Easiest solultion is to download 7zip and use it to expand the archive.